# EEG Keyboard Emulator

Tags: game-engine, external-applications

I am using an EMOTIV Epoc to emulate a keyboard. EMOTIV is a company that develops sophisticated brain-monitering devices. One can read about them [here](http://emotiv.com/).
My device sends the keystrokes just fine into applications like Word, but when I try and use it with the Blender Game I have created it doesn't seem to work. I'm also using a Macbook Pro, if that helps. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

keyboard emulators or keystroke generators often make use of the Operating System's UI functionality to send the keystrokes to applications. Since Blender comes with its own UI the codes won't be recognized.

I don't know much about Mac OS and Macs in general because I don't use them anymore but maybe there are other tools that provide the functionality on a lower OS level. There certainly are some for Windows.

Comment: I agree with that assumption. The BGE directly listens to the keyboard device (driver) rather than listening to the key-code mapped OS-layer. The reason is simple: Game usually need the exact event when and if a key is pressed, while text-input-applications wants the resulting character. The later ignore keys that are hold longer than 1/60s until a certain delay. This would be deadly for a game.